# Firestore Data Update the Page Refresh automatically

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I use `listen()` in retrieving data from Firestore. I am also using `setData` and `merge: true` to update the data in Firestore. When there is an update in the Firestore it will automatically refresh the whole page. How can I stop that from doing so. I want it to change the value but not refresh the page. Is it possible? Any documentation or sample code is welcome. Thank you in advance.

**Update**

This is my `DropDownButton`:

```
Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            DropdownButton(
              items: routeName.map((value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              underline: SizedBox(height: 0,),
              onChanged: (value) => setState((){
                selectedItem = value;
                polylineCoordinates.clear();
                getRoute();
              }),
              hint: new Text ("Select a Route"),
              value: selectedItem,
            )
          ],
        ),),
```

This is where I add in the value in the `DropDownButton`:

```
List <String> routeName = [];
    
Future <void> getRouteName() async{
        Firestore.instance.collection('routes').snapshots().listen((RouteData) async {
          routeName.clear();
          if(RouteData.documents.isNotEmpty){
            for (int i = 0; i < RouteData.documents.length; i++){
              if(i == 0){
                routeName.add("No Route");
              }
              routeName.add(RouteData.documents[i].documentID);
            }
          }
          setState(() {
          });
        });
      }
```

This is my `initState()`

```
@override
  void initState(){
    geoService.getCurrentLocation().listen((position){
      centerScreen(position);
    });
    geoService.getCurrentLocation().listen((position) {
      _addGeoPoint(position);
    });
    getMarker();
    getRouteName();
    retrieveRoute();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is where things go wrong:

```
 Future <void> getRoute() async{
    if (selectedItem == "No Route"){
      var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(user.email).setData(
          {"Route": "No Route"}, merge: true);
    }
    var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(user.email).setData(
        {"Route": selectedItem}, merge: true);
  }
```

Because I want it to update to the Firestore whenever I update the value in the `DropDownButton`, but after the update it will refresh my page and I don't want it to refresh the whole page. I just want it to save to Firestore and update at the `DropDownButton` only.

Comment: Can you share your code that is not working as intended?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to listen to a Stream just one time, you may use the **first** operator on it:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('routes').snapshots().first.then(() => {
  // this will be called juste once
});
```

Comment: I don't want that, I want them to listen all the time but do not refresh the whole page when there is changes in the Firestore. Still thanks for your generous answer.

Comment: What if you remove your setState from the listen callback?

Comment: Trying it still the same. There is a error message saying "There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.". Is this related to this?

Comment: Found it on the internet. It is not related to this topic. It was my FloatingActionButton that causes this.

Comment: Found out the problem. The page refresh because my Document have a lot of field when there is a changes it will refresh the page. I made a new collection to store them and I am able to make some changes without refreshing the page. Thanks for the help as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your `getRouteName` method.

```
Future <void> getRouteName() async{
    Firestore.instance.collection('routes').snapshots().listen((RouteData) async {
      routeName.clear();
      if(RouteData.documents.isNotEmpty){
        for (int i = 0; i < RouteData.documents.length; i++){
          if(i == 0){
            routeName.add("No Route");
          }
          routeName.add(RouteData.documents[i].documentID);
        }
      }
      setState(() {
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Every time you call `setState`, it will cause the UI to be repainted. Since you use `listen` to get called for any changed to `routes`, and call `setState()` for every such change, any change to `routes` will repaint the UI.

If you don't want to repaint the UI altogether, remove the call to `setState()`. If you want to repaint the UI only in certain conditions, wrap the call to `setState()` in those conditions.

Comment: After removing the `setState` it still reload when I change the value in the Firestore.

Comment: Found out the problem. The page refresh because my Document have a lot of field when there is a changes it will refresh the page. I made a new collection to store them and I am able to make some changes without refreshing the page. Thanks for the help as well. Thank you.